# Convert txt file into html table by using c++

Tags: c++

I want to convert text file into HTML tables but can't create columns.It inputs the whole data into rows.[As you can see in the picture there are no separate columns for each section.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGIPl.png)

```
#include<iostream> 
#include<fstream>
#include<string> 
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
void main()
{
    ifstream x;
    string name;
    string head = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<head> <style> table, th, td { border: 1px solid black; } </style> </head><body>\n<table>";
    string tail = "</table></body>\n</html>";
    string bodystart = "<tr><td>\n";
    string bodyclose = "</td></tr>";

    ofstream y; 
    x.open("example.txt",std::ios::app);
    y.open("myhtmlfile.html");

    y << head;
    while (getline(x, name)){
        y << bodystart << name <<bodyclose;
    }
    y << tail;
    x.close();
}
```

Comment: [this is bad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). Also should `void main` be `int main`. Also fix the formatting of the code

Comment: You're taking each line from the file, and wrapping it inside a `<tr>` with exactly one `<td>`. If you want multiple columns, put each field inside a `<td>` element. What exactly is your question?

Comment: that's the problem I don't know how to put each field inside a <td>tag.@SamVarshavchik

Comment: So really you wanted to ask a question about how to split/parse data out of lines from a text file... Perhaps searching for stuff like "c++ how to split lines of text" would yield some useful techniques.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to provide  tags for each item in a line when you read a line from the file

Currently only 1  tag is added for each row. hence you see only 1 column for the table. To add multiple columns, you need to add multiple  tags for column item

You can use a delimiter to split the column items in a line and then loop through the individual elements adding  tag

Example:

```
while (getline(x, name)){
    y << "<tr>";
    for(int i=0;i<noofcolumns;i++) {
        y << "<td>";
        // y << columnItem;
        y << "</td>";
    }
    y << "</tr>";
}
```

Hope It Helps.